# groovy sql connection per database

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, groovy, connection-pooling

I have a SQL query service that can query different SQL databases based on user parameters. Is there functionality that already exists to reuse a SQL connection based on the database it is connecting to?

For example, I want to do something like:

```
def executeQueryAgainstDatabase(dbName) {
    if ( connectionExistsFor(dbName)) { 
        sql = getConnectionFor(dbName)
    }
    else {
        sql = Sql.newInstance(...)
    }       
}
```

This isn't really that difficult to implement, but I wasn't sure if there was something with existing connection pool capabilities that I could leverage.

Answer (score 1):

The entire java ecosystem is available in groovy... why not use DBCP? http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/

Comment: I haven't actually used DBCP before. It looks like it has some pooling capabilities but is it possible to pool based on the data source?

Comment: I dont' see why not... just create one instance of the connection pool per datasource.